# How to get disk ID using C# (not "SerialNumber")?

Tags: c#, disk

I'd like to retrieve the **Disk ID** of my hard drive using C#.

I do not want "SerialNumber" as most articles talked since it's absent on my box.

To check this **ID**, you can run "cmd" on windows:

```
  diskpart
  list disk
  select disk 0
  detail disk
```

The output is like:

```
  HGST HTS725050A7E630
  Disk ID: 1033D54D
  ...
```

On my virtual box the output is

```
VBOX HARDDISK
Disk ID: 22452244
```

The disk ID seems to be a 32bit integer.

Is there anyway to get the same thing using C# (using API instead of parsing cmd output)?

Answer (score 2):

This value is stored as the 'Signature'.  You get this the same place that you get the Serial Number.

```
ManagementObjectSearcher win32DiskDrives = new ManagementObjectSearcher("select * from Win32_DiskDrive");
foreach (ManagementObject win32DiskDrive in win32DiskDrives.Get())
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0:X}", win32DiskDrive.Properties["Signature"].Value);
}
```

Comment: When I run the steps you provided for diskpart, I get Disk ID E3D125A4 - when I run the  code above, I get: E3D125A4.  Tried it on 15 different disks and get matching values every time.

Comment: Thanks yes it is. I used a tool to check it but I did not notice it was displayed in decimal format.

Answer (score 1):

You could use WMI and the [Win32_DiskDrive](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394132(v=vs.85).aspx) class. There are both a `DeviceID` and a `SerialNumber` properties, you might want to check if it contains the value you're looking for.

Comment: DeviceID is the same on all computers like "\\.\PHISICALDRIVE0".

Comment: @LeonZeng Could you enumerate all properties of the class to see if any of them contains the value you're interested in?

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to add an interesting information that `diskpart` (or macrium reflect) display disk ids which are in different numeral system than signature ids displayed by Wmi cmd/powershell commands like `Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_DiskDrive` or `wmic diskdrive`. These Wmi structures can also be used in C or C# programs or powershell scripts.
This can be quite confusing and may suggest difference between disk ids and signatures but these numbers are actually the same but written in different numeral systems.

In Diskpart (or macrium reflect) display disk ids are in hexadecimal numeral system.
In Wmi commands signatures are in decimal numeral system.

Example output of diskpart:

```
diskpart
select disk 0
detail disk
KINGSTON SUV400S37120G
Disk ID: 006BDFF5
Type   : SATA

select disk 1
detail disk
SAMSUNG HM160HI SCSI Disk Device
Disk ID: 04E77F0E
Type   : USB
```

Example output of Wmi commands:

```
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_DiskDrive | select Description, DeviceID, Model, Signature

Description DeviceID           Model                            Signature
----------- --------           -----                            ---------
Disk drive  \\.\PHYSICALDRIVE1 SAMSUNG HM160HI SCSI Disk Device  82280206
Disk drive  \\.\PHYSICALDRIVE0 KINGSTON SUV400S37120G             7069685

wmic diskdrive get Description,DeviceID,Model,Signature

Description  DeviceID            Model                             Signature
Disk drive   \\.\PHYSICALDRIVE1  SAMSUNG HM160HI SCSI Disk Device  82280206
Disk drive   \\.\PHYSICALDRIVE0  KINGSTON SUV400S37120G            7069685
```

`7069685` decimally equals to `006BDFF5` hexadecimally.
`82280206` decimally equals to `04E77F0E` hexadecimally.